# How to display .pdf files from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, joomla

Dear All I'm able to display the images from mysql. But when I want to display the pdf that also stored in my database I'm not able to do that. When I use this code this code show  a small green piece of image but not the .pdf files. This code well works on image . But I'm not able to show .pdf files.
can any help me to tell me where in my code I have to cahnge . And I request please give the proper change line that is able to show PDF file.
thanks in advance`

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $dbname     = "db_dat";
    $password   = "";


    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $passno="";
    $doi="";
    $doe="";
    $poi="";
    $empid='';
    $emp_name='';
    $desg='';
    $comp_add='';
    $dob='';
    $img='';


   if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $passno=$_POST['pass'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['dateofissue'])) {
        $doi=$_POST['dateofissue'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['dateofexpiry'])) {
        $doe=$_POST['dateofexpiry'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['issueplace'])) {
        $poi=$_POST['issueplace'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['issueplace'])) {
        $poi=$_POST['issueplace'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
        $empid=$_POST['content'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $emp_name=$_POST['name'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['designation'])) {
        $desg=$_POST['desgination'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['companyaddress'])) {
        $comp_add=$_POST['companyaddress'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['dateofbirth'])) {
        $dob=$_POST['dateofbirth'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
        $img=$_POST['image'];
    }



    $sql = "SELECT * from upload WHERE EMP_ID='".$empid."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       $img= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
       $passno=$row['passport_no'];
       $doi=$row['dateofissue'];
       $doe=$row['dateofexpiry'];
       $poi=$row['placeofissue'];
       $empid=$row['EMP_ID'];
       $emp_name=$row['employee_name'];
       $desg=$row['designation'];
       $comp_add=$row['company_address'];
       $dob=$row['dateofbirth'];
    }
?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


        <body>
            <form method="POST" action="" >
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Enter Employee Id</td> <td><input type="text" name="content"   id="content"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" class="FormSubmit"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Employee Name</td> <td>        <?php echo $emp_name; ?> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Employee desgination</td> <td> <?php echo $desg; ?> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Company Address</td> <td>      <?php echo $comp_add; ?> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>DOB.</td> <td>                 <?php echo $dob; ?> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Date of Issue</td> <td>        <?php echo $doi; ?> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Date of Expiry</td> <td>       <?php echo $doe; ?> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Place of Issue</td> <td>       <?php echo $poi; ?> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Passport Image</td> <td>       <?php echo $img; ?> </td></tr>
                    <div class="space"></div>
                    <div id="flash"></div>
                    <div id="show"></div>
                    </div>
                </table>
            </form>    
        </body>
    </head>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are adding image instead of pdf...there isn't any tag with `<pdf` like we have for image so create a clickable link.There is a different between pdf and image.

Your clickable link will be generated by

```
 $img="<a href='"$row['image']."'>Download </a> ";
```

Another way is to use iframes

where you will create an iframe and open the pdf in iframe

```
 echo" <iframe src='"$row['image']."'></iframe>";
```

`row['image']` must have a complete path like

```
 http://hostname.com/uploads/yourPDFfile.pdf
```

Comment: Dear Danyal I wanna tell that all my PDF files are stored in database with type BLOB.

Comment: And when I replace my                                                                               $img= '<img src="data:image/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';         with your      $img="<a href='"$row['image']."'>Download </a> ";                    then some    Image ‘ eŒf–€ (¢€ (¢€ (¢€çúÑEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQ              like code I got and when I click on that code      I got the page that says   Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying pdf file first check if its pdf then give path of pdf image from your directory

Answer (score 0):

For displaying pdf file you have to set proper headers also to display the file.
Try setting these headers and replace $filename with your file path.

```
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Comment: Dear Vickrant I think You didn't readmy code properly . Iwant to display pdf files as well as text too. If  I use                                                                 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  your code my whole page only show pdf file not a single text .  So please I request you to give the code that will display both pdf files and text.  And for your kind information I want to tell my pdf is stored in database whose type is BLOB not in server.